# WPS: can the client ever play the registrar role?

Tags: wireless-networking

In a WPS (wireless protected setup) system, can a client, e.g. a mobile phone, a wifi-enabled laptop, etc ever play the role of an external registrar?

Comment: external registrar to what exactly?  You are aware that WPS is broken and not secure right?

Comment: Yes. At work, a college told me that when using WPS with AP Pin, the client actually acts as an external registrar. I'm not so sure about that. Hence the question.

Comment: Please provide your definition of an "external register"

Comment: @Ramhound External registrars are well-defined in the WPS spec.

Comment: @Spiff - Feel free to explain if its that well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Wi-Fi Simple Configuration specification (the WPS specification) v2.0.2 has explicit instructions for how a Wi-Fi device can act as the external registrar. I don't have earlier versions of the spec handy, so I'm not sure how far back this support goes. But I suspect that even in version 1.0, any device that's already on the network can act as the external registrar, because one form of the external registrar protocol is UPnP based, and UPnP is just UDP/IP based, so any device that's already IP-reachable when the AP needs it could potentially run the necessary software and be configured to act as the external registrar.